# Error htaccess to hide php extension, just hide html

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem to hide php extension on my website using htaccess.
I saw a lot of webs to try to fix it and nothing.
But just html extension is hidden for me.

On my htaccess I have this to hide extensions (it's right after errors pages what is the first on my htaccess, but I don't think that influences):

```
#hide extensions 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I can access to html files without extension, but for php files, I can't (404).

I deleted htaccess file and created it again but nothing.
And of course, on links to php and html files, I don't put the extension (for example url/file instead of url/file.php).

Comment: Presumably you don't have HTML and PHP files that share the same file path and basename?

Comment: @MrWhite all php and html files are at the same level as the htaccess file, at the root path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `.htaccess` file is in the document root of your site then try the following instead:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [L]
```

The `$1` backreference in the `RewriteCond` *TestString* (ie. `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php`) is a backreference to the captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `(.+)`), ie. the requested URL-path. This is the same backreference as used in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* (ie. `$1.php`).

A bit more explanation...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
> ```

The condition here that checks the existence of the requested resource *plus* the file extension is not strictly correct, depending on your file structure. It's not necessarily checking the same file that you will ultimately rewrite to in the following `RewriteRule`. See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error) for a detailed explanation of this.

The `L` flag is missing on the `RewriteRule`, so processing will continue through the file and could be getting rewritten again.

`MultiViews` needs to be disabled (if not already) for the rewrite to be successfully processed. This probably does not affect you currently, but if your rewrite included URL parameters; they would be missing. (The effect of MultiViews is that mod_negotation would issue an internal subrequest for `file.php` *before* your mod_rewrite directive is processed.)

Comment: It works perfectly! I don't know why everything I tried before didn't work for me when for others it did. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that resolved the problem. I've added a bit of explanation to my answer.

Comment: Could you please explain how the `$1` is interpreted in the conditions?

Comment: @arkascha The `$1` backreference in the `RewriteCond` _TestString_ refers back to the captured group in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (ie. the requested URL-path). Just the same as the `$1` backreference in the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ (ie. `$1.php`). You could use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead (eg. `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php`) - the result would be the same here. (In fact, if the `.htaccess` file was located in a subdirectory, not the document root, then you would _need_ to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable here.)