# how to use multiple get requests .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Hello there i have a little problem.

When using these lines of `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymLinks

# clean up file extensions .php only
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#make get request clean
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^cms/tests/([0-9]+) cms/tests/index.php?survey=$1 [NC,L]
```

I transform the url 
`cms/tests/index.php?survey=65` to -> `cms/tests/65`

This works!

Now i want to have an edit mode like this:

`cms/tests/65/edit` or `cms/tests/65/view`

This is the rewrite rule I have come up with:

```
RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymLinks

# clean up file extensions .php only
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#make get request clean
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^cms/tests/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) cms/tests/index.php?survey=$1&mode=$2 [NC,L]
```

When writing the full url like this `cms/tests/index.php?survey=65&mode=edit` it completely works

But it with the "clean" url it goes to my 404 page and also shows a 302 redirect in the network tab.

[image: Network tab]

Is there a something that I am doing wrong or over seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> #make get request clean
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
> RewriteRule ^cms/tests/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) cms/tests/index.php?survey=$1&mode=$2 [NC,L]
> ```

The second condition is never successful so the rule is not processed.

The second condition (that supposedly checks that the request + `.php` exists) is not what you should be doing here. If anything, you would need to check that the request does not map to a file. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

However, if you restrict the regex in your `RewriteRule` *pattern* by appending a `$` (end-of-string anchor) then you can remove that condition altogether. For example:

```
#make get request clean
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cms/tests/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ cms/tests/index.php?survey=$1&mode=$2 [NC,L]
```

A request that matches the regex as stated could not map to a real file (unless you have extensionless files).

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> # clean up file extensions .php only
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

The second condition in your first code block is also not strictly correct and will fail under certain conditions, because the filesystem check is not necessarily the same as the file you will ultimately rewrite to, which could result in a 404 or 500 (rewrite loop) depending on your file structure. (This code block is surprisingly common, but [issues relating to this keep on cropping up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59919247/error-htaccess-to-hide-php-extension-just-hide-html).)

This should really be written more like this:

```
# clean up file extensions .php only
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now, the condition `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php` matches the rewrite *substitution* `$1.php`. (Assuming the `.htaccess` file is in the document root.)

See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to the following question on ServerFault with a detailed explanation of this change: https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment much <3

Comment: I have one little problem again... When using your method for the get request I still get an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` I think it is because for some reason it tries to put my js file behind my get requests [image](https://imgur.com/a/ick06Yg) Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: That is most probably caused by using relative URL-paths in your client side code (resulting in "404" errors - which your code is trying to interpret as JSON). You need to use root-relative (starting with a slash) or absolute URLs throughout. When you are at the URL `cms/tests/65/edit` then any relative URL for a client-side resource is naturally going to be relative to this URL - which is what you are seeing in your screenshot.